# OpenCV: Where do I find documentation for sample codes?

Tags: opencv

After I compiled openCV libraries, I got the following directory:

opencv\build_2.4.9\samples\ocl

In this there are many sample codes. But no description is provided unless you read the complete code and  run a couple of times to know what it does.

Are there any documentation for such sample codes? If not how do I go ahead?

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV has got examples mentioned in their websites
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html

Or refer to 
**Learning OpenCV: Computer Vision with the OpenCV Library**
by Adrian Kaehler and Gary Rost Bradski

Comment: None of these talk about OCL examples